# Adding an image for faild downloads in universal image loader

Tags: android, android-listview, xamarin.android, universal-image-loader

In my monodroid application I use universal image loader to display images on a list view .
Before displaying images i show a progress bar on images.
I wanna add an default images for when the download fails.
Is it possible?
This is the code that i display image with it:

```
    ImageLoader = Com.Nostra13.Universalimageloader.Core.ImageLoader.Instance;
ImageLoader.DisplayImage(myobject.Images [0], imageView,  Application.Options, newImageLoaderListener (progressbar));
```

This is a monodroid code.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is possible, if the download fails you should have some kind of flag or trigger to identify the failed image then display your default image.

Comment: how i can detect the download had failed?

Comment: IF after downloading the bitmap, downloadedBitmap == null? error : success. Similar situation

Comment: i just use display image function of universal image loader and all other thing done by this library itself. therefore how can i detect when the bitmap in null while i pass an image view to display function of image loader

Comment: Can you show the code where you actually set the `ImageView`s `Bitmap`?

Comment: Show please your ```progressbar``` listener.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ImageLoadingListener.onLoadingFailed()` for that. Display your image in `onLoadingFailed()`.